# Sending items to database and making a receipt in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

We have another IT project, and this time it's on VB.NET, it's actually going pretty good compared to the one we did on Java. So it's still a POS System, and I have six functions of the POS (for admins, and 4 for employees). Right now I'm  almost done with the Cash Register function. I have a problem, though. The menu items are in buttons, and once you click a button, it appears in three listboxes (one for item name, quantity and price), and once a button is clicked more than once, it looks for the string with its name and updates the price and quantity. A keypad is adjacent to the buttons, for the input of the customer's payment. Once btnTransact is clicked, it checks for equality of the total amount and the amount paid. So it goes through if else statements and once everything is niff and dandy it shows that the transaction is completed in a message box.

I need the items in the listboxes to appear in either a form or a message box (if that's possible), but I don't know how. Also, I need the listbox items to be sent to a database, tbl_Invoice with columns "Invoice Number (autonumber)", "Invoice Date (there's a realtime clock in my POS)", "Product Code (in tbl_Products, each item has a specific item code", "Quantity", "Unit Price", "Employee ID (I have a log-in as well, and I need to get the Employee ID based on the logged-in user from tbl_Employees)". I will provide appendices.

Also, I have partially added a DisplayDeceipt sub just in case.

I'm sorry if I do not know a lot about VB.NET, only basic functions are being taught to us, and what they're asking from us is waaaay beyond basic. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you[image: ![My Cash Register layout]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O47xD.png)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmCR
    Dim intTotal, intPlace As Integer
    Dim quantCCS, quantSalad, quantKare, quantGarlic, quantAdobo, quantMushroom, quantAsul, quantDilaw, quantBasket, quantIslands As Integer
    Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        txtPaid.Text += btn1.Text
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn2.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn3.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn4.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn5.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn6.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn7.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn8.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn9.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btn0_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btn0.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btnDeci_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeci.Click
    txtPaid.Text += btnDeci.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtPaid.Clear()
End Sub
Private Sub btnCCS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCCS.Click
    quantCCS += 1

    If quantCCS = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("CAESALAD")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantCCS)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("160")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("CAESALAD")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantCCS)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 160
    End If

    intTotal += 160
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub tmrCR_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCR.Tick
    lblTime.Text = Format(Now, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
Private Sub frmCR_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tmrCR.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub btnSalad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSalad.Click
    quantSalad += 1

    If quantSalad = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("BBFSALAD")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantSalad)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("160")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("BBFSALAD")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantSalad)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 160
    End If

    intTotal += 160
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnKare_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnKare.Click
    quantKare += 1

    If quantKare = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("KAREKARE")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantKare)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("210")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("KAREKARE")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantKare)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 210
    End If

    intTotal += 210
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnGarlic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGarlic.Click
    quantGarlic += 1

    If quantGarlic = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("TAPAO")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantGarlic)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("180")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("TAPAO")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantGarlic)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 180
    End If

    intTotal += 180
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnAdobo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdobo.Click
    quantAdobo += 1

    If quantAdobo = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("ADOBODILAW")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantAdobo)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("145")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("ADOBODILAW")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantAdobo)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 145
    End If

    intTotal += 145
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnMushroom_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMushroom.Click
    quantMushroom += 1

    If quantMushroom = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("MUSHCHICKEN")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantMushroom)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("160")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("MUSHCHICKEN")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantMushroom)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 160
    End If

    intTotal += 160
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnAsul_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAsul.Click
    quantAsul += 1

    If quantAsul = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("KNGASUL")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantAsul)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("35")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("KNGASUL")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantAsul)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 35
    End If

    intTotal += 35
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnDilaw_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDilaw.Click
    quantDilaw += 1

    If quantDilaw = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("KNGDILAW")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantDilaw)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("35")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("KNGDILAW")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantAsul)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 35
    End If

    intTotal += 35
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnBasket_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBasket.Click
    quantBasket += 1

    If quantBasket = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("ICECRMBASKET")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantBasket)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("110")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("ICECRMBASKET")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantAsul)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 110
    End If

    intTotal += 110
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnIslands_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIslands.Click
    quantIslands += 1

    If quantIslands = 1 Then
        lstItems.Items.Add("TSOKOISLAND")
        lstQuant.Items.Add(quantIslands)
        lstPrice.Items.Add("180")
    Else
        intPlace = lstItems.FindStringExact("TSOKOISLAND")
        lstQuant.Items(intPlace) = (quantIslands)
        lstPrice.Items(intPlace) += 180
    End If

    intTotal += 180
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal
End Sub
Private Sub btnTransact_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTransact.Click
    Dim intAmount, intPricePaid, intLack, intSuffice As Integer
    If txtPaid.Text <> "" Or (lstItems.Items.Count = -1) Then
        intAmount = lblTotal.Text
        intPricePaid = txtPaid.Text
        If intAmount > intPricePaid Then
            intLack = intAmount - intPricePaid
            Do
                intSuffice = InputBox("Insufficient amount paid. Please ask Php " & intLack & "." & vbNewLine & "Enter amount:", "Insufficient Amount", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                intLack = intLack - intSuffice
            Loop While intLack > 0
            If intLack = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed. There is no change. Here is your receipt.", "Transaction success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                lstItems.Items.Clear()
                lstQuant.Items.Clear()
                lstPrice.Items.Clear()

                txtPaid.Text = ""
                intTotal = 0
                lblTotal.Text = "0.00"
            ElseIf intLack < 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed. The change is Php " & intLack * -1 & ". Here is your receipt.", "Transaction success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                lstItems.Items.Clear()
                lstQuant.Items.Clear()
                lstPrice.Items.Clear()

                txtPaid.Text = ""
                intTotal = 0
                lblTotal.Text = "0.00"
            End If
        ElseIf intAmount = intPricePaid Then
            MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed. There is no change. Here is your receipt.", "Transaction success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            lstItems.Items.Clear()
            lstQuant.Items.Clear()
            lstPrice.Items.Clear()

            txtPaid.Text = ""
            intTotal = 0
            lblTotal.Text = "0.00"
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed. The change is Php " & intPricePaid - intAmount & ". Here is your receipt.", "Transaction success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            lstItems.Items.Clear()
            lstQuant.Items.Clear()
            lstPrice.Items.Clear()

            txtPaid.Text = ""
            intTotal = 0
            lblTotal.Text = "0.00"
        End If
    ElseIf txtPaid.Text = "" Or (lstItems.Items.Count = -1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a value.", "Null value", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub DisplayReceipt()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Everything is, but I do not know how to send this data to a database.

Comment: What ***is not working***. There's more than a few questions here as well which is too broad to answer. Can you please try and focus on one thing per question as when there's more than one it doesn't help others that come looking for an answer. Recommendations: look into classes, research databases and how to query them, turn Option Strict On. That's a few to get going.

Comment: `but I do not know how to send this data to a database` I understand, we have all been there. It's very broad to answer here... Do a search first on what DBMS you want to use, I don't know the requirements and go from there.

Comment: You are welcome! If you get stuck come back and ask for help.